# iOS: How to draw color contour using OpenCV

Tags: ios, iphone, opencv, colors, contour

I am working on an iPhone App which has to detect the blue color object from the preview and change it to yellow color using drawcontour api. I tried a lot but the contour is drawn in white color. I searched a lot but I could not solve my issue. My code as Follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];    
   self->videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
   self->videoCamera.delegate = self;
   self->videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
   self->videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset =
   AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
   self->videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation =
   AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
   self->videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
   self->videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;    
   [videoCamera start];
}
```

**Delegate to get the frames:**

```
-(void)processImage:(cv::Mat &)image
{
    cv::Mat image_copy = [self convertToYellow:image];       
}
```

**Convertion Method**

```
- (cv::Mat)convertToYellow:(cv::Mat)image
{    
cv::Mat cameraFeed = image;
cv::Mat HSV, threshold;
cv::cvtColor(cameraFeed, HSV, CV_BGR2HSV);    
cv::inRange(HSV, cvScalar(90,50,50), cvScalar(130,255,255), threshold);

cv::Mat erodeElement = getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT,    cvSize(3,3));
//dilate with larger element so make sure object is nicely visible
cv::Mat dilateElement = getStructuringElement(  cv::MORPH_RECT,cvSize(3,3));

erode(threshold,threshold,erodeElement);
erode(threshold,threshold,erodeElement);

dilate(threshold,threshold,dilateElement);
dilate(threshold,threshold,dilateElement);   

cv::Mat temp;
threshold.copyTo(temp);
cv::vector< cv::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours( temp, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0) );

bool objectFound = false;
if (hierarchy.size() > 0) {

    for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {

        cv::Moments moment = moments((cv::Mat)contours[index]);
        double area = moment.m00;


        if(area > 500){

            objectFound = true;

        }else objectFound = false;
    }

    //let user know you found an object
    if(objectFound ==true){

        for(int i=0; i < contours.size() ; i++)
        {      
                    cv::drawContours(cameraFeed,contours,i,cvScalar(0,255,255),CV_FILLED);

        }

    }

}

return cameraFeed;

}
```

**Actual object**

[image: Actual object]

**After the contour is drawn**

[image: preview after the contour is drawn]

Someone please help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: `cv::drawContours(cameraFeed,contours,i, Scalar(0,255,255,255),CV_FILLED);` just to be sure

Comment: It worked!! Very Silly:)  Thanks alot @Miki

Comment: @Vinothios can you share your code for this please?

Comment: Hi, that was a poc I did in my previous company. I dont have the code now.. I am sry @Premal Khetani

Comment: @Vinothios no worries that's fine. Can you help me to correct my code? actually, I am getting output with contour drawn but not filled with color. only outline.

Comment: ok Share ur code.. @Premal Khetani

Comment: @Vinothios here is code https://codeshare.io/2KvZLN

Comment: @Vinothios if you can correct the code just edit it in the code and add a comment. your help would be great for me. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just add the alpha parameter in the scalar() function of ur drawContour method as I modified in ur code. @Premal Khetani

Comment: Thanks, @Vinothios got the point but I just got the result. But there is no filled part. I got exact lines but the not filled.